# Create fail2ban filter for Wordpress under nginx

Tags: wordpress, apache, nginx, logging, fail2ban

I'm trying to create a fail2ban filter for wordpress under nginx, but its not working and need some help.

The Log:

```
111.111.111.111 - - [27/Oct/2019:02:54:48 +0200] "POST /wp-login.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1697 "http://my-wordpress.com/wp-login.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 13_1_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.0.1 Mobile/15E148 Safari/604.1"
```

Filter:

```
[INCLUDES]
before = common.conf

[Definition]
failregexe = <HOST> - - .* "POST /wp-login.php .* 200
ignoreregex =
```

Jail:

```
[wordpress]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = wordpress
logpath = /var/log/nginx/access.log
maxretry = 3
bantime = 3600
```

Test Regex

```
#fail2ban-regex /var/log/nginx/access.log  /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/wordpress.conf

Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : wordpress, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use      datepattern : Default Detectors
Use         log file : /var/log/nginx/access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:

Lines: 72 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 72 missed
[processed in 0.01 sec]

Missed line(s): too many to print.  Use --print-all-missed to print all 72 lines
```

Whats wrong on this regex?

I tried also

```
^<HOST>.*"POST./wp-login.php.*200.*$
^<HOST> - - .* "POST /wp-login.php .* 200
```

and many more....

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo (remove last `e`):

```
- failregexe = ...
+ failregex =
```

BTW: do you really want to ban 200th response? (200 means OK). 
Additionally your regex is too "vulnerable", better use something anchored and more precise, like this:

```
^<HOST> - \S+ \[\] "[A-Z]+ /wp-login.php [^"]+" 200
```

Or even use `(?!- )\S+ ... [54]0\d+` instead of `\S+ ... 200` if you want capture other codes and for users with real username only (so would ignore handshake requests where user logged as `-`).